# Are cantina battle shipments always the same?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

In Star Wars Galaxy of Heroes, are the cantina battle shipments always the same?

It appears they never change after they reset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Cantina shipments (as well as the shipments for Galactic War and Squad Arena) are static. The timer simply indicates when you are next able to purchase a character you have recently purchased.

Note that characters will occasionally be added to shipments (and potentially replaced or removed as the developers see fit). For example Qui-Gon Jin has just been added to the Cantina, while Captain Phasma was added to Galactic War late last year.

The only shipment that changes which characters are available is the Shipments from the main screen.

Comment: I'm pretty confused by this whole answer. They're static, but they change. Which is it? Elaborate? Also, what in the world is that last sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: @DCShannon Cantina shipments always hold the same content each time, except when the developers (rarely) add a new character. The daily shipment (I can't think of another name for it), however, changes its content each time it resets. Also note that this answer is from February last year and I no longer play the game, so there may be changes that make my answer obsolete.

Comment: So, the characters in the other shipments don't change unless we're notified, but the characters in the credit-based shipments change randomly.

Comment: The guild shipments change at every refresh as well.